# Ruby on Rails XML generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, file-io

I am attempting to build a simple method that creates an XML file from a database in ruby on rails. I feel like my code is right but I am not seeing all of the users in the XML.
I am a complete newbie to RoR.

Here's my code:

```
def create_file     
  @users = User.find(:all)
  file = File.new('dir.xml','w')
  doc = Document.new

  make = Element.new "make"
  @users.each do |y|
    make.add_element "name"
    make.elements["name"].text  = y.name
    make.add_element "description"
    make.elements["description"].text = y.description
  end    

  doc.add_element make

  file.puts doc
  file.close
end
```

And my XML output:

```
<make>
 <name>sammy</name><description>samsdescription</description>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
 <name/><description/>
</make>
```

I don't get why all the fields aren't populated. Why is just one of the database entires showing up? I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in your code. In each iteration you create an element with [`add_element`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/classes/REXML/Element.html#M003015) and then try to access that element with [`Elements#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/classes/REXML/Elements.html#M002900). But when you use a node name in `Elements#[]` it returns only the first matching node. So you are creating a node in every iteration but updating only the first one. Try to change the code to the following:

```
@users.each do |y|
  name_node = make.add_element "name"
  name_node.text  = y.name
  desc_node = make.add_element "description"
  desc_node.text = y.description
end
```

By the way, your XML structure is a bit strange. Wouldn't it be more clear if you wrapped every name/description pair inside another node (say, *user*) and then have many *user* nodes?

Comment: Yeah, there isn't much use to this right now, i am just playing around to try and learn it. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

You ought to investigate `@users.to_xml` to see if it is something you could use instead of rolling your own solution. Read more about it in the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions.html#M000798).